# Which pandas DataFrame row raised a warning with apply function?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, warnings

I have a DataFrame in which each row is one observation and each column a parameter. I need to apply a function to each row, and in some of them it raises a `warning` but I can't find out which ones. Example:

```
result = df.apply(lambda x: func(x, args), axis=1)
```

If `df` has 1000 rows, 500 will raise an identical warning message from `func`, but there's no way for me to know which ones.

Is there a way to output the DataFrame's rows that raised the warning and save them to a list, for example?

Comment: You can define func to include a print() on x with x being the x in lambda x as in your example.  Then it will print out the row content together with the row index.

Comment: Did you solve this problem? If the answer below worked, please accept it.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. The solution below doesn't print each row individually, it prints a whole batch of rows and I still couldn't figure out which ones were getting the warning message. Although I found a way to circumvent the problem and deal with the warning in another way (it was actually a function from statsmodels and I just did a better cleaning of the data and the only warnings left were unimportant for my analysis). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If this is for troubleshooting (vs production) you can use `df.iterrows()` to apply the function and print or log the row number, for example

```
for n, row in enumerate(df.iterrows()):
    print(row)
    func(row, args)
```